# Array associativo ou objeto para salvar meta-dados temporarios?

Tags: php

Tenho um sistema que fará um parser de paginas web, durante o processo o parser deverá armazenar alguns dados sobre a pagina como: tipo da pagina (dinamica, estatica), tamanho(em bytes) estes dados sobre a pagina devem ser salvos em um array associativo ex: `$meta_dados[tipo] = 'dinamica';` ou em um objeto? não será armazenado em nenhum local esta informações tendo assim uso somente durante o parser

Comment: As duas tem suas vantagens. Na minha opinião é mais organizado com objeto. A propósito, acho que a pergunta vai ser baseada em opiniões no final das contas.

Comment: Eu acho que depende do estilo do seu código. Se tudo for orientado a objeto, faz mais sentido usar um objeto pra isso também. O array associativo é um coringa em PHP, serve pra qualquer coisa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vai do gosto do freguês, não há uma forma correta nesse aspecto, a melhor forma é a que te atenda. Só tente manter a coerência, se sua aplicação foi implementada usando orientação a objetos, faça uma classe para manter os metadados.
Se está usando a forma procedural não faz muito sentido colocar uma classe para armazenar os metadados e sim usar direto uma variável como o array.